# Generic Selection sort that can check object fields

Tags: java, sorting, generics, arraylist, selection-sort

What I need to do is take a file that would contain a name field and then also have data with them and sort them based on a given number that represents a certain set of that data. Here is an example text file. This would be like cities and their average temperature for each month(not actually accurate).

```
NewYork: 35, 28, 99, 39, 3, 15, 52, 5, 6, 97, 36, 32
Baltimore: 1, 59, 55, 0, 92, 82, 23, 60, 23, 16, 75, 75
Seattle: 19, 18, 10, 36, 50, 2, 8, 36, 56, 86, 14, 91
Atlanta: 57, 75, 52, 66, 28, 58, 53, 5, 21, 30, 81, 58
```

I want to be able to sort these based on a given data point, so if 2 was selected it should be sorted by the second point in ascending order so it would look like this. The actual data for each city is not being sorted, the whole data set is being either moved up or down based on the data point that is being used.

```
Seattle: 19, 18, 10, 36, 50, 2, 8, 36, 56, 86, 14, 91
NewYork: 35, 28, 99, 39, 3, 15, 52, 5, 6, 97, 36, 32
Baltimore: 1, 59, 55, 0, 92, 82, 23, 60, 23, 16, 75, 75
Atlanta: 57, 75, 52, 66, 28, 58, 53, 5, 21, 30, 81, 58
              ^
             This is the second data point row that was sorted.
```

Here is what the selectionsort class is looking like, and I could get it to work without generics but I want to be able to use generics.

```
public class SelectionSort{

private SelectionSort(){

}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(ArrayList <T> arrayList, int key){

    for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size() -1; i++)
    {
        int smallestIndex = i;

        for(int j=i+1; j<arrayList.size(); j++)
        {
            if(arrayList.get(smallestIndex).compareTo((arrayList.get(j))) > 0  )
            {
                smallestIndex = j;
            }
        }
        T temp = arrayList.get(i);
        arrayList.add(i,arrayList.get(smallestIndex));
        arrayList.add(smallestIndex, temp);

    }

}
```

Then for the actual objects I have this where the input to the constructor is simply one whole line from the text file. Then the data handle and name handle help to split the String up and set name to the name from the text file, and set the arraylist to be all the numbers that the name had with it.

```
public class ObjectData<T> {
private ArrayList<Integer> list;
private String name;



public ObjectData(String objectInfo){

    String array[] = allData(objectInfo);
    this.name = nameHandle(array[0]);
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(dataHandle(array[1])));
}



private static String[] allData(String string){

    String array[] = string.split(":");


    return array;

}

private static String nameHandle(String string){
    String name = string.trim();

    return name;

}

private Integer[] dataHandle(String string){
    String array[] = string.split(",");
    String trimmedArray[] = new String[array.length];
    Integer integerArray[] = new Integer[trimmedArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        trimmedArray[i] = array[i].trim();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < trimmedArray.length; i++){
        integerArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(trimmedArray[i]);
    }


    return integerArray;
}



public String getName(){

    return this.name;

}


public Integer getIndex(int index){


    return list.get(index);

}
```

}

In main all the objects are put into an arraylist, and that would be the arraylist of objects that is then inputed into the SelectionSort class. The problem I am having is figuring out how to use a the generic selection sort with an object like this. I was planning on just calling for example if the key was 2 like above. I would call

`if(arrayList.get(smallestIndex).getIndex(2).compareTo((arrayList.get(smallestIndex).getIndex(2))) > 0  )`

instead of `if(arrayList.get(smallestIndex).compareTo((arrayList.get(j))) > 0  )`

The only other way I was thinking about being able to do this was instead of creating objects I would just put all the information into a 2d array and then be able to compare them, but then I lose the name for the data. If anyone can suggest how I should change this to make it work, or a totally different way to accomplish this, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

One way you might consider is creating an object that implements the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and takes the index to sort on as a parameter:

```
public class DataComparator implements Comparator<ObjectData>{
    private int sortIndex;

    public DataComparator(int sortIndex){
        this.sortIndex = sortIndex;
    }

    public int compare(ObjectData t1, ObjectData t2) {
        return (t1.getIndex(sortIndex) < t2.getDataIndex(sortIndex)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

If you then have a `List<ObjectData>` of your cities, let's call it `cityList` for the sake of example, you can sort it using `Collections.sort(cityList, new DataComparator(2))`.

Comment: Alright I think I understand, except how would I then use the DataComparator in the Collections.sort method? Wouldn't I have to right a new sort method that uses the DataComparator's `compare` method? Which would then again make it not able to use generics.

Comment: `Collections.sort()` already makes use of the `Comparator` you pass into it. You just need to create an instance of it that sorts using the index you want, and pass that instance to `Collections.sort()` just like the example at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way. Just wondering though wouldn't the second parameter for the sort method have to be changed to accept an object? Also confused still since I am using compareTo in the sort method and what you show when implementing Comparator shows a compare method rather then a compareTo.

Comment: By "the sort method" do you mean `Collections.sort()`? If so then no, the second parameter for that is a `Comparator`. Note that with this approach you wouldn't be using your own `sort()` method since `Collections.sort()` is itself a sorting algorithm. You should have a look at the Javadocs for [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).